# Can you increase text limit of program output?

Tags: c, output, codeblocks

Im running a program,in CODEBLOCKS,that associates numbers in arrays and then finds the mean average. I have 25 samples and would like to copy the output and put it into word to print it.However, the output window cuts off samples 1-11 and only shows 12-25. I added getch() so i can copy and paste as i need, but just wondering if there is a way to increase output text limit. Thanks. Code below if it helps you understand

```
int main()
{
    int x,high=1,low=0;

    for (x=0;x<25;x++)
    {
        calcPercent(low,high);
        high++;
        low++;
        getch();
    }

return 0;
}

void calcPercent(int low,int high)
{
    int x,y;
    float valid,mean,total=0;

for (x = low ;x < high;x++)
{
    for ( y = 0; y < 20; y++ )

    float percent[500]
    int sample[25][20]

    //This is just the top part of the function
```

Comment: I am not using codeblocks, but are you sure that there is no scroolbar in the output window?

Comment: Are you using windows console as output? If yes, you can increase it's output screen width and buffer width to accommodate whole output (this is what I have done for my self).
You can try to output to a text file and copy from there. PS: I haven't worked on Codeblocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just write the output to a text file? You're probably using printf anyway and the call to fprintf has the same syntax (except you give the file handle as the first parameter. This link has a short example on how to write to a file: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/

Comment: Thanks, i ended up copying and pasting in short amounts, but thats way easier